# iOS push notification work on terminal of mac same certificate not work on .net backend?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push

Apple Push Notification Services ios tutorial 1/2 for raywenderlich follow the command on mac terminal and get notification on my iphone using php script.
but my mobile app same on .net desktop i used my certificate in this app here show the message deliver successfully but not getting on device in development and in production mode.
please help me.

Comment: For .net you dont need to create  PEM File. Because PEM file is only required for php code, for .net direct certificates will be used.

Comment: The specifics of what PEM is doesn’t really matter (in fact, I have no idea) but it makes it easier for PHP to use the certificate. If you write your push server in another language, these following steps may not apply to you. according to raywenderlich